# how to pass django view data in js to get product id accordingly

Tags: python, django

> the problems is i have passing data from view to product template , when i click add to cart i have to get product id accordingly using js how can i do this inside templates it work but when i apply inside script it doesn't work  is there any method to access / get data

> my `views.py`

```
def product(request):
    productbyid = None
    categories = ProductCategory.get_all_categories()
    products = TopList.get_all_products()
    categoryID = request.GET.get('category')
    
    if categoryID:
        productbyid =TopList.objects.filter(category=categoryID)
        
    else:
        productbyid = TopList.get_all_products()
    data = {}
    data['categories']:categories
    data['productbyid'] =productbyid
    data['products'] = products
    data['categories'] =categories
    
    return render(request,'product.html',data)
```

> my `product.html`

```
    % for pbyid in productbyid %}

<div class="card card_body m-2 p-0 container" id='{{pbyid.id}}'>
<div>
  <div>
  <a href="/viewpage/{{pbyid.id}}"><div class='imagestyle' ><img class="card-img-top " src="{{pbyid.image}}"width="500" height="200" alt="Card image cap "></div></a>
  <span class="top-left">{{pbyid.discountpercentage}}% off</span>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title cardtitle">{{pbyid.title}}</h5>
    <div><p class="carddesccrip">{{pbyid.desc}} </p></div>
    <div class='pricce_card'>
    <span class='price'> <b>M.R.P</b> <strike class='carddesc'>RS {{pbyid.discountPrice}}</strike></span>
    <span class='final_price'><b>RS. {{pbyid.finalprice}}</b></span>
    
</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
  {% comment %} /viewpage/{{pbyid.id}} {% endcomment %}
     <button href="" class="btn btn-lg btn-block addbtn caddtocart" onclick="myFunction()" > Add to cart {{pbyid.id}} 
     <i class="fa fa-plus float-right align-center p-2 plusbtn" aria-hidden="true"></i></button> 
  </div>
  </div>



  </div>

 {% endfor %}
```

> `js` ,  my try  here i when i click `caddtocart` btn i have to get product id accordingly but it doesn't work .

```
    <script>

var x = document.getElementsByClassName("caddtocart");
function myFunction() {
d = "{{products}}";
data = parseInt(d); 
console.log(data);

}
 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can pass variables from a template to JS like so:

```
onclick="myfunction({{pbyid.id}})"
```

this will pass the id to the function for you then in your js you get the parameter like:

```
myfunction(id){}
```

Comment: can you tell me how i can change the innerHTML according to the product id i try `document.getElementsByClassName("caddtocart").innerHTML = "Paragraph changed!";
`  but it doesnt work can you help here

Comment: i would need more information than that, from this i would debug using chrome dev tools and see if it is getting an element, also if your original question is answered could you mark it as answered in case anyone else has the same issue

Comment: from this same question i there is class name `caddtocart` in a for loop in above template  i just try to change. btn and some html value by `getElementsByClassName` but it doesnt work i haven't changed other things just try to change innerHTML of add to cart

Comment: this would be out of the scope of the question, i would ask a new one and provide all the info for it